# Want to download jar with package org.jboss.messaging.jms.server.management

Tags: jboss, jms

Want to download jar which contain package
org.jboss.messaging.jms.server.management

can u suggect any link.
Also any clue how to use MessagingServerControl to create JMS queue at run time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the package is a part of JBoss messaging version 2. The download page is here:

http://www.jboss.org/jbossmessaging/downloads